# Show only a certain part of the x-axis when using plot(density(mydf))

Tags: r, plot, kernel-density

There's an extreme value in my data. How can I only show the density plot for the "important" part of my data. I'd like to show the x-axis only from let's say -5 to +5 percent.

```
COMP <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
RET <- c(-80,1.1,3,1.4,-0.2, 0.6, 0.1, -0.21, -1.2, 0.9, 0.3, -0.1,0.3,-0.12)

mydf <- data.frame(COMP, RET, stringsAsFactors=F)

plot(density(mydf$RET))
```

and the same with boxplot on the y-axis

```
boxplot(mydf$RET)
```

I know

```
boxplot(mydf$RET, outline=FALSE)
```

but here I want the range of the y-axis even smaller. How is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Could do `plot(density(mydf$RET), xlim = c(-5, 5))` and `boxplot(mydf$RET, outline=FALSE, range = 0.5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the arguments `xlim` and `ylim` to adjust the axis' scales in R basic graphics.

```
COMP <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
RET <- c(-80,1.1,3,1.4,-0.2, 0.6, 0.1, -0.21, -1.2, 0.9, 0.3, -0.1,0.3,-0.12)
mydf <- data.frame(COMP, RET, stringsAsFactors=F)

par(mfrow = c(1,2)) #stack plots in 1 row and 2 columns

plot(density(mydf$RET),xlim=c(-5,5), main="")
boxplot(mydf$RET, ylim = c(-2,2), ylab="RET")
```

[image]